# Iam intergrating Instamojo on my app ,ERROR

Tags: android, instamojo

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.parse.starter"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}}repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
}}dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'ai.devsupport.instamojo:instamojolib:0.1.6'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
```

}

ERROR A) when I compile it,, it showing me like this

Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [ai.devsupport.instamojo:instamojolib:0.1.6] /Users/subhashchandru/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/instamojolib-0.1.6.aar/275ce458a79a76a5caa040ee469ca7b5/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="instamojo.library" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

---

ERROR B)When I lower the SDK version  it showing me like this

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found. 
failed linking references.

Comment: what do u mean when u say u lowered the sdk version? Dont you have to increase hte minSdkVersion in your project to 15?

Comment: yeah have done that then it is showing me another errro B

Comment: Replace all instances of 'compile' with 'implementation' and clean build